# When I try a syncdb, where is the duplicate user_id error coming from?

Tags: python, django, django-models, sqlite

The traceback is on a '''python manage.py syncdb''', and happens immediately after the password is entered twice. The database is sqlite3.

The traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 109, in handle_noargs
    emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 190, in emit_post_sync_signal
    interactive=interactive, db=db)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 172, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 70, in create_superuser
    call_command("createsuperuser", interactive=True)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 166, in call_command
return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 134, in handle
    User.objects.create_superuser(username, email, password)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 140, in create_superuser
    u = self.create_user(username, email, password)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 136, in create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 460, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 570, in save_base
    created=(not record_exists), raw=raw, using=using)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 172, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/Users/jonathan/pim/accounts/models.py", line 12, in create_user_profile
    UserProfile.objects.create(user = instance)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 138, in create
    return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 360, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 460, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 553, in save_base
    result = manager._insert(values, return_id=update_pk, using=using)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 195, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, values, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1436, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 791, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLInsertCompiler, self).execute_sql(None)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 735, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 34, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 234, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column user_id is not unique
```

My models.py is below:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.db.models import ForeignKey
from django.db import models
from accounts.models import UserProfile

class CalendarEvent(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    when = models.TextField()
    def __init__(self, when, description, user_profile):
        self.when = when
        self.description = description
        self.user_profile = user_profile
    def accepts(timestamp):
        if isinstance(timestamp, float):
            timestamp = time.asctime(time.localtime(timestamp))
        if timestamp[:4] == 'days':
            pass
        else:
            if re.match(self.when, timestamp):
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

Removing the underscore from all user_profile references does not change this behavior.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix it?

--EDIT--

The source for the project is at http://JonathansCorner.com/project/pim.tgz.

Comment: Can you please post the model.py for the accounts app that you created, so that we can see what you did with your UserProfile? Also it looks like you aren't calling the `__init__()` of your superclass in your `CalendarEvent.__init__()`

Comment: For me it looks like the class CalendarEvent is not responsible for the error you get. There seems to be an error with the user_id attribute of some other model, maybe the UserProfile from your accounts app?

Comment: I agree with @jdi - your `__init__` method looks unnecessary. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Django does a lot of work behind the scenes when you declare a model field, so you can't just set them in your `__init__` method in the same way that you can regular attributes.

Comment: I've refactored out the __init__() and uploaded the new source to the address above. I'm still getting the same complaint.

Comment: Did you test the answer posed by @Alasdair regarding blowing away your UserProfile table first? He is suggesting that you have a user profile already existing, and then it goes and tries to create another UserProfile from your attached signal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are connecting the User post_save signal twice, because you are importing the account models module on two different paths. This means you are trying to create two user profiles for your new super user, and it fails the second time.

When Django imports the accounts app, the path for the models is accounts.models. However when django imports the pim 'app' (it isn't really an app, it's the project root, more on that later), the accounts.models module is imported again as pim.accounts.models.

The quickest way to fix the problem is to use a [unique identifier](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signal) when connecting the post save signal.

```
post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender = User, dispatch_uid="create_user_profile")
```

The better fix is to sort out your imports and project layout:

- create a separate app for your models.py that contains the CalendarEvent model, instead of putting it in your project root.
- you can name your app 'pim' inside your project 'pim' if you want
- move your models.py, admin.py and possibly some if your urls to the new app

If you are currently developing, then the easiest thing to do is to drop the user profile table and let syncdb recreate it. Alternatively you could delete the unneeded user profiles in the shell.

Comment: You beat me to pressing the save edits button, but when I started tapping it out you hadn't mentioned signals yet :-)

Comment: What's the best place to put the save.connect() call? I put it in admin.py, imported by urls.py, and it's complaining about importing User (the import is 'from django.db.models import User'). Where should I be putting this, and what (if anything) else should I do so it matches your line of code?

Comment: The connect call is fine where it was in your `accounts.models` module, *if* you use `dispatch_uid`, or fix up your project structure. The `User` import should be from `django.contrib.auth.models import User`.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: My previous answer was removed in place of this correct answer...*

The issue is that your post_save signal is being connected multiple times every time the `accounts.models` is imported by anything. What you actually want to do is relocate the signal connection to a `management.py` file inside your accounts app

**accounts/models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    scratchpad = models.TextField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    timezone_offset = models.IntegerField(default = 0)


def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user = instance)
```

**accounts/management.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from accounts.models import create_user_profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender = User)
```

django will load your management.py module one time, so there is now only one signal being connected, regardless of how many times your accounts.models is imported.

Comment: I just fixed my answer. The previous one was wrong. Yes I agree though that everything should really be an app, and not have models in the root. But the real reason is that his signals are being connected many times.

Comment: These two answers make me regret that I can only mark one answer as correct. Thank you, and on to splitting into apps.

Comment: You can only mark one answer as correct, but you can still upvote his answer ;)

Comment: Or we can take turns. MWF @Alasdair can have the checkmark. And the other days of the week you can unmark him and set mine as the answer.